# drawing balls from an urn

Tags: probability, self-study, combinatorics

Suppose there are 7 golf balls in an urn and you draw balls in 3 stages without replacement.  First you draw 2, then 3, and then the remaining 2.  How many ways are there to do this?

I believe the answer would be ${7\choose 2}{5\choose 3}$ but I am making this question up so  would like to verify the answer.

Comment: A definite improvement. Is there anything in particular making you unsure of your answer? Can you explain the reasoning by which you arrive at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer appears correct.

In particular, the number of ways will be the number of ways of choosing groups of 2,3 and 2 from a set of 7.

This is the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) ${7 \choose 2, 3, 2} = \frac{7!}{2!\, 3! 2!}$.

As you state in your question, its value is equal to ${7\choose 2}{5\choose 3}$, which you can arrive at via a number of different routes.